# Less.js rules are not applied immediately

Tags: css, less

I'm using less.js inline preprocessor for development, and its been working fine so far.

However, I've just changed the main layout file from .css to .less, and it started causing issues on page load. Namely, when I reload the page, I can see the unstyled layout for a fraction of a second, just before the rules are applied.

Moreover, when jQuery UI tabs are initialized, they end up reading incorrect container height, and do not update after the styles are loaded, leaving me with very small tabs until I resize the window.

Is there any way to force less.js to compile the rules before the page is displayed/loaded?

Comment: Don't use `less.js` - compile the `.less` file to a `.css` on your computer first and then upload and use the `.css` file in your site. As you are observing, `less.js` compiles the `.less` CSS file on the clients computer and it's unnecessarily expensive and doesn't load immediately (first the client has to download `less.js`, then they have to download the `.less` file, then the `.less` file has to be parsed - http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage

Comment: I mentioned I'm only using it for development. Of course I compile it for production, but running the compiler every time I need to see the effect of the changes I just made is slightly overkill. I'm running good old apache and setting it up to compile rules when I request them is quite a bit of work.

Comment: Try a build system: Gulp and Gulp-less http://gulpjs.com/ https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's not a local development environment so that's why you are actually noticing the flash of unstyled content, in that case...

What about the load order? I.e only load jQuery ui plugin after less.js has loaded.